# How to prove that $\mathrm{E}\left[ \left \| \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{x}_i \right \|^2 \right] = n$ for random vectors of unit-length?

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, random-walk

While tinkering with some numerical simulations of random walks using random vectors of unit-length, I stumbled upon the following:

Say, we have $n$ random vectors, $\mathbf{x}_i \in \mathbb{R}^{d+1}$, where "random" means uniformly sampling the unit $d$-sphere, then it appears that the following is true:

$$
\mathrm{E}\left[ \left \| \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{x}_i \right \|^2 \right] = n
$$

where $\left\|\cdot\right\|$ is the Euclidean norm, and $\mathrm{E}\left[\cdot\right]$ is the expected value. To me, this is the kind of thing you would derive as an approximation at large $n$ using the central limit theorem, but numerically this expression seems to be exactly true for all $n$ and $d$, even for small $n$.

For $d=1$, this is just a simple random walk and easy to prove. But I don't know how to prove this generally for arbitrary $n$ and $d$.

Comment: Your question should be rephrased as if $n$ points are selected uniformly, **Independently** and randomly from the unit sphere. Then $E(||\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{i}||^{2})=n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\mathbb E\left[\left\|\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf x_i\right\|^2\right] &= \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb E\left[\left\langle \mathbf x_i, \mathbf x_j\right\rangle\right] \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb E\left[\left\|\mathbf x_i\right\|^2\right] + \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1,\, j\neq i}^n \left\langle \mathbb E\left[\mathbf x_i\right], \mathbb E\left[\mathbf x_j\right]\right\rangle\\
&= n
\end{align}

Comment: Ah, I see! The cross-terms disappear because they are uncorrelated on average, so $\mathrm{E}\left[\left\|\sum x_{i}\right\|^{2}\right] = \mathrm{E}\left[\sum\left\| x_{i}\right\|^{2}\right] = n$

Comment: Ah, never mind - you got rid of your hints and replaced it with an answer.

Comment: @XYZT The "uncorrelatedness" has to be assumed beforehand

Comment: @AlexOrtiz Korki is writing $E(\langle x_{i},x_{j}\rangle)=\langle Ex_{i},Ex_{j}\rangle$ that requires independence.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz Otherwise if you really think about it, if we just restrict to two vectors and chosing $x_{2}=-x_{1}$ would result you with $0$ norm.